# How can I remove all non-alphabetical characters of any language in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building an app that uses a tagging system like SO. I don't want to except any non-alphabetical characters, but I do want to allow actual letters of any language.
Using a filter to only allow certain letters seems unreasonable, as I don't have a collection of all possible letter of every language, so I think the right way to go around it would be to block the characters that aren't allowed.
But even then, there are 1000s of characters that should be blocked.

How should I go around it? Is there some magical array out there that holds all these characters?
How do other products usually tackle this?

Would love ideas, thanks!

Comment: Are you going to target all browsers and JS environments? If you want to support ECMAScript2018+, you may use `.replace(/\P{L}+/gu, '')`. You may also use `XRegExp`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there an option to add to this regex to also allow for white space?

Comment: Certainly, `.replace(/[^\p{L}\s]+/gu, '')`